# Delete request in React

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

I have a List on my page that display all registered users from a collection in Mongodb and Now i have created an Admin Panel that I want to be able to delete users with the click of a button but I have no clue about how to construct such a function.

This is the component that renders users:

```
class UsersList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super();
  this.state = {
    usersData: []
  };
}


componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3003/api/inlogg').then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function (result) {
      this.setState({
        usersData: result
      });
      }.bind(this))
  }

  render () {
    return this.state.usersData.map(function (user) {
                return <div className="dropdown" key={user._id}>
                  <li>{user.userName}</li>
                  <div className="dropdown-content"><Link to={"/privatchatt/"+user.userName+"/"+sessionStorage.getItem("username")} target="_blank"><p>Starta privatchatt med {user.userName}</p></Link>
                    <button className="delete-btn">Delete</button>
                  </div>
                </div>;
              }
            )
          }
        }
```

Here is my express delete route (Its working with postman, also "users" is the collection name)

```
    app.delete('/api/users/delete/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  users.deleteOne({ _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id) }, (err, result) => {
    if(err){
      throw err;
    }
    res.send(result)
  });
});
```

This is what is in my db:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b6ece24a98bf202508624ac"), "userName" : "admin", "passWord" : "admin" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b6edb95fbbd8420e4dd8d20"), "userName" : "Admin", "passWord" : "Admin" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b6eea7f0becb40d4c832925"), "userName" : "test4", "passWord" : "test4" }
```

So what i want to create a fetch delete request that goes off when i press a delete button from my React front-end

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So you'll want an onClick handler on your `button` in the render function. Then in that handler, make a fetch request with the method `DELETE` to the API url.

```
handleClick = userId => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'DELETE'
  };

  // Note: I'm using arrow functions inside the `.fetch()` method.
  // This makes it so you don't have to bind component functions like `setState`
  // to the component.
  fetch("/api/users/delete/" + userId, requestOptions).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((result) => {
    // do what you want with the response here
  });
}

render () {
    return this.state.usersData.map((user) => {
      return <div className="dropdown" key={user._id}>
        <li>{user.userName}</li>
        <div className="dropdown-content"><Link to={"/privatchatt/"+user.userName+"/"+sessionStorage.getItem("username")} target="_blank"><p>Starta privatchatt med {user.userName}</p></Link>
          <button onClick={() => { this.handleClick(user._id) }} className="delete-btn">Delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>;
    })
  }
}
```

For the most part, my code above is pretty standard. There's just one really wonky thing that I did on your button element in the render function. I didn't just pass in a reference to `handleClick` like you normally would. I wrapped it in a function (an arrow function, specifically). That's because we want pass in a parameter that's not the click event to the `handleClick` function. Then I'm having `handleClick` pass in the user id as the parameter. This is because we want the function we defined to accept the ID of the user you want to delete.

Comment: Hey bwalshy,Thanks a lot ...I was struggling to implement delete functionality ..with your answer.I got the solution.